# How to access a Provider setter method

Tags: angularjs

I have a Provider that I use to set some configuration, based on the environment.

```
(function() {
angular.module('testProvider').provider('TestProvider', TestProvider);
function TestProvider() {
    var foo = {
        'bar' : '123456',
    };
    return {
        setFoo: function(foo_data) {
            angular.extend(foo, foo_data);
        },
        $get: function() {
            return foo;
        }
    };
}
```

}) ();

I can access the shared config object: `TestProvider.bar` works fine in a controller or runblock.

But I am struggling to invoke `setFoo` in the Config module: it complains that the provider is unknown. What am I missing?

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/philcms1/Lmm2pv5y/).

Answer (score 0):

Angular appends "Provider" automatically to the reference injected. This [corrected JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/philcms1/Lmm2pv5y/4/) works fine.

Here is the module:

```
(function () {
angular.module('fooApp').config(['TestProviderProvider', testConfig]);
function testConfig (TestProviderProvider) {
    console.log('Setting up the context!')
    TestProviderProvider.setFoo({
        'bar' : '654321'
    });
}
```

})();